# AngularJS: directive uses separate scopes for template and controller/link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use directives for templating but unfortunately each directive appears to set up individual scopes for template and controller/link functions.

Example at [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/x91LziJwYtpvnUWLGMwr):

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <h2>Directive with Isolating Scope</h2>
    <isolating some-value="isolated">{{someValue}}</isolating>

    <h2>Directive with Shared Scope</h2>
    <sharing some-value="shared">{{someValue}}</sharing>
</body>
```

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.directive('isolating', function(){
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'scope': {
      'someValue': '@'
    },
    'transclude': true,
    'template': '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    'link': function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.someValue = attrs.someValue;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('sharing', function(){
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'transclude': true,
    'template': '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    'link': function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.someValue = attrs.someValue;
    }
  };
});
```

What I see with Batarang: (directive names in parentheses)

```
< Scope (002)
    < Scope (003)    <= (isolating) contains the isolated scope
    < Scope (004)    <= (isolating) contains the template scope
    < Scope (005)    <= (sharing)   contains the shared scope
```

How can I use the isolated scope 003 for the template? Scope 004 seems completely unnecessary.

AngularJS version is 1.2.0-rc3.

Comment: OK, seems I really simplified my example too much. In my application I'm nesting multiple directives similar to those above and want to pass on parts of a parent scope while adding new variables from the same directive because they are required on a deeper nested level. So I really need to pass the isolated controller/link scope to the transcluded part and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the template attributes from both.

Edit: With this particular template, you should note that transclusion creates a sibling scope to the isolate scope that inherits from the parent.  The text is going to use the transcluded scope, so it has no knowledge of the value from the isolate scope.

If you switch `{{someValue}}` to `{{isolated}}` in the DOM, you will see what is happening I think.

Comment: Sorry, simplified it too much to post the question and missed it. Templates should have contained <div ng-transclude></div>, correcting my question in a minute. // done; divs got lost when posting the question, was visible on plnkr

Comment: Well, I really simplified it too much. :) Added an explanation to my question. Is there any way to get the scope passed on to the transcluded part?

Comment: Unfortunately no - transcluded scopes are separate from isolate scopes, which gets its information only from the parent as specified by directive attributes.